# Js document.getElements explanation?

Tags: jquery, html, triggers, getelementsbyclassname

I have some issues with js code (again^^). On a project, I call a (kind of) modal with a js code in my "main.js" that use "document.getElementById" to trigger the modal...

Problem, I would like to trigger the modal with multiple links around the page.. So I tried to use "document.getElementsByClassName" instead but that doesn't work at all ! (of course I made all the change needed in the html part)

Thanks for your help!

That is the Js code : (I'm learning js)

```
(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-contact' ),
    overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.contact-overlay' ),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'},
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };
function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );}
            classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );};
        if( support.transitions ) {
            overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );}
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }}
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
        classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
    }}
triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );})();
```

The html is (part of):

```
<div class="contactico"><i id="trigger-contact" class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
<div class="contact-overlay">
    <button type="button" class="overlay-close">close</button>
        <div>test</div>
</div>
```

So the point is that I have more than one link that need to trigger the "contact-overlay".

When I tried, I changed the first line into : (of course I change the html aswell)

```
(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-contact' ),
```

Comment: When you use `getElementsByClassName/TagName/Name()` you'll get what is called a HTMLCollection. It's a list of every element that is targeted and this list is an 'array-like' object. 'array-like' objects are not true arrays, but you can find out how many elements in the list and rudimentary things like for loops. [They can be converted to a true array to be more useful](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/187/arrays/2333/converting-an-array-like-object-list-to-an-array#t=201608141118062395534).

Comment: BTW, your example would be easier to analyze if you had some HTML and in a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, if all of these `.trigger-contact` are bound to the same event and the event handler is the same, there are easier ways to go about it.

Comment: Well I'm sure you know what you are doing, but I don't. I don't think you know what my answer to your problem is, but I certainly know that knowing the layout is very important. You are manipulating the DOM, therefore HTML is important. If that's the HTML you have and nothing else then you should have no problem at all. That's perplexing...I reply before your msg?

Comment: Yeah, well read the previous reply, and good luck to you.

Comment: Yep that's the point, I would like multiple links triggering the same action... I update the post... And sorry I was editing the comments and make mistake. Sorry I thought that was understandable!! So the point with the html is that I don't want copy all the code... Imagine a simple page with for example one link a the top and one at the bottom that trigger the same "modal/overlay" (with a code located at the bottom)...

Comment: @zer00ne. I think I understand why you needed to see the layout... One link is a <div> and the other a <li> !! Sorry I'm learning... ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get it !! I found a way by changing the first line and add some code:

```
triggerBttn = document.querySelector('div.trigger-contact'),
triggerBttn2 = document.querySelector('li.trigger-contact'),
```

and add at the bottom:

```
triggerBttn2.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
```